# Ruby Gem for user address location filling from zip/post code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

It's quite common these days for site input forms for home address to ask the user for zip/post code and then provide drop down options to the user to select the entire address after having done a lookup from the zip/post code.

Is there a ruby gem or good API to get this functionality integrated into a RoR application?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a good experience with [Area](http://rubygems.org/gems/area)...

```
zip = 35205
city, state = zip.to_region(city: true), zip.to_region(state: true)
```

I don't know of any libraries with view helpers for generating such a form, you'd have to build it yourself as far as I know. Shouldn't be much trouble.

Comment: That looks excellent!  
Any idea if there is an equivalent for UK based post codes and addresses?

Comment: Area uses [this file](https://raw.github.com/jgv/area/master/data/zipcodes.csv)... With a little parsing, you should be able to add some [rows for UK](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/postal/GB.txt) to extend support for those post codes. As an alternative, you may prefer Google's [geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).